# Changing Target.Address location based on iterations vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that inserts rows based on a cell value in cell J17 using Target.Address. I'd like to use the similar code on the line below it; however, the location of the line below it is dependent on the number of rows that are added.
Does anyone know of a method to add the number of iterations to the rows of an address?
I know how to do this using Cells function, but I like the automatic running of the Target.Address

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Address = "$J$17" Then
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Target.Value
        Cells(18, 9).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(18, 9).Value = i
    Next i
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Make the cell in $J$18 a Named range, and then refer to it by name. This is dynamic, and moves with the worksheet changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of a method to add the number of iterations to the rows of an address?

Sure. That part is elementary. You could compute the range's new address using the `Offset` method.  But then you need to store it somewhere. You could create a `CustomDocumentProperty`, a hidden worksheet or a named range variable. All of these would work just fine.

But probably the best solution is just to define that cell initially as a named range. Named ranges are neat because they are dynamic.  If you insert rows/columns or delete rows/columns, the `Name` moves with the cell. Then, in your code, just compare versus that range's `.Address` property, instead of hard-coding in a value like "$J$18".

Here's how:

First, define a named range for cell J18. I named it "insert", but you can name it (almost) anything you want. Just make sure to update the reference to it in the code.

[image]

Use something like this if you are going to do *different* operations depending on which Target is changing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
'This handles your original J17
If Target.Address = "$J$17" Then
    For i = 1 To Target.Value
        Cells(18, 9).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(18, 9).Value = i
    Next i
End If

'This handles the new named range:
If Target.Address = Range("insert").Address Then
    'Do something else, here:
    MsgBox "Success!!"

End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you are doing the *same* insertion and numbering, then I would fancy it up like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If .Address = "$J$17" Or .Address = Range("insert").Address Then
            For i = 1 To .Value
                .Offset(1, -1).EntireRow.Insert
                .Offset(1, -1).Value = i
            Next i
        End If
    End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```